# Blender to Unity Armature Animation Deformations

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, 3d-modelling

My animations are deformed in Unity, mostly on the legs of the model, but you can also see it on the head:

[Video with the animation on Blender vs Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqEV-TANk7Y)

I found it particulary weird that the mesh deforms this way in the head, there's no bone in blender that I can move to make the mesh look like this:

[image]

What I tried:

- Import blend file directly to Unity
- Export to fbx from Blender, then import to Unity (I followed 4 possible configurations from different answers, nothing changed)
- Checked that the weight paint of vertices was ok
- Removed some bones from the legs, it helped but the mesh still deforms in different ways

What can I do to fix this situation so that the rig+mesh animation matches what I'm seeing on Blender?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as well. I don't know if you already tried it but what I did was:

1. Import from blender to fbx
2. Open your Unity project
3. Click on "Assets" (above the hierarchy. File/Edit/Assets...)
4. "Import New Asset"
5. Choose your fbx horse file
   6.Your horse should appear in the Project panel
6. Drag it to your scene

Tell me if it helped!

Comment: I can confirm, that importing an exported fbx is a difference in comparison to importing the blend-file. The blend-file didnt show deforms during animation, in my case.